# Django static files uploaded to folder in Amazon S3 that can't be found

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up Django so that all static files are uploaded to s3, but for whatever reason, it's not working. Here is the relevant section in `settings.py`:

```py
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-east-2"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = (
    f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com"
)
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}"
AWS_LOCATION = "static"

STATIC_URL = f"{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{AWS_LOCATION}/"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
```

Supposing that my bucket is called bucket_name, this is what will happen:

- In my bucket_name bucket, there will be a folder called "bucket_name" with a static folder inside which contains all of my files.
- On the server, none of the assets will load. This is because they are looking for the url https://bucket_name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static whereas it's written in https://bucket_name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/static.

How do I either get the django assets to use this new address, or change the address on aws so that it aligns with django?

I've done some things to debug this.

- It seems that if I redefine `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` after all of these lines, all that will change is the folder name will change from bucket_name to whatever else. Except I don't want to rename this folder, I want to either remove it entirely or get django to understand this folder.
- Changing `STATICFILES_STORAGE` doesn't seem to do anything, unless it gets removed, which will cause an error
- Changing the `AWS_LOCATION` just changes the folder to bucket_name/<new_thing>/static, it has no effect on the base folder. This will make the assets use <new_thing>/static, but the bucket_name still isn't there.
- Temporarily removing my bucket policy doesn't fix any problems.

I imagine my problem is similar or the same as the one here: [why static files and images are not working on my django s3 bucket project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503799/why-static-files-and-images-are-not-working-on-my-django-s3-bucket-project). But it did not get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was using both `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` and `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL`. I had to pick just one of them.

When `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` is specified and not `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` , S3 will contain a folder according to `AWS_LOCATION`, so in my case, the static files are stored in https://bucket_name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static. Django will access this URL and the assets will be found.

When `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` is specified and not `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`, S3 will contain a folder with the bucket name, which contains a folder according to `AWS_LOCATION`. So I can access it with https://bucket_name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/static. Django again will be able to access this URL as would be expected.

The problem arises when I have both at the same time. The domain for `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` will be used on django and `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` will be used on S3, resulting in the disconnect that I was having.